# React-Admin: Is there an event which is triggered when a list/datagrid item is selected?

Tags: reactjs, events, datagrid, react-admin

I'm looking for the event which displays the bulkaction-toolbar (the "xx items selected reset view-button delete-button"-toolbar) when a list/datagrid-item is selected. Here is an gif-example: [bulkaction-toolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jELlM.gif)

the following event is fired when the 'select-all' checkbox is clicked by the user

```js
    <Datagrid onSelect={arr=> console.debug('datagrid->onselect:', arr)}>
```

additional question: if I use this event like above the checkbox is never checked when the user clicked on it. Is this a bug or how i make working it?

Comment: React is a reactive framework, it reacts to state changes and not events. So there is no such event.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: @FrançoisZaninotto if there is no such thing how is the bulkaction-toolbar implemented?
the usecase: if the user selects a row from the grid the id has to be sent to a backend which sends data to the frontend and the frontend has to render this data on a leaflet map ;)

Comment: The selection checkbox in the datagrid doesn't expose any way to hook your own logic. You'll have to use a custom component instead.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone stumbling upon this, 2 things to keep in mind.

1. There are 2 event handlers, `onSelect` and `onToggleItem`. The first is triggerd on bulk select, the 2nd is triggered on individua select
2. The moment you give one of these event handlers to `Datagrid`, it switches into a controlled component mode, meaning you also need to give it the `selectedIds` prop for it to display the selected items. You will have to track your own list of selected identifiers (e.g. with `useState`)